# using UDF in datatable for datagridview

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, datatable

I am passing a DataTable object into a Windows Form and binding the DataTable to a DataGridView. In the DataGridView I allow a user to edit and add data / rows. I need to display the results of two calculations on the DataGridView depending on the data that the user enters. The calculations are results of 2 methods that get called from events on the DataGridView. Those work great during an active edit or use of the DataGridView.
After a user saves the items I return the DataTable object to a class that saves the data to the underlying table.

The problem I have is when a user opens the Windows Form again to edit a record, my calculations do not show because events have not been fired on the DataGridView that would trigger the respective methods.

So, I was thinking that I could send the calculated fields along with the DataTable object, or I need to hook the calculation methods to more events in the Windows Form / DataGridView.

If I send the calculated fields along with the DataTable, that would cause issues with returning the DataTable object for the database update actions right?

I would appreciate thoughts and / or suggestions.
Thanks

I can post any relevant code if it helps.

****this code handles data changes in the grid view cells****

```
private void datagridWorkorderPartItems_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    int ID;
    HighlightSaveItems();
    DataGridViewRow row = this.datagridWorkorderPartItems.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex];
    if (!DBNull.Value.Equals(row.Cells[3].Value) && !DBNull.Value.Equals(row.Cells[2].Value))
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 2 || e.ColumnIndex == 3)
        {
            decimal price;
            decimal originalprice;
            decimal partmargin;
            Pricing p = new Pricing();
            ID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);

            //if price all ready has a value or has been altered, don't change it
            price = p.GetPartItemPrice(ID);
            originalprice = price;
            Parts part = new Parts();
            partmargin = part.LookupPartMargin(ID);
            //now take the price and check against customer price level
            decimal pricelevel;
            decimal invertedpricelevel;
            string level;
            Customers c = new Customers();
            level = c.GetCustomerPartsLevel(_cid);
            Options o = new Options();
            pricelevel = o.GetPartsLevelPercent(level);

            //get proper percent - 100
            if (pricelevel == 1)
            {
                invertedpricelevel = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                invertedpricelevel = 1 - pricelevel; //inverted the percent
            }

            price = price * invertedpricelevel;

            try
            {
                if (e.ColumnIndex == 3) //column 3 is part id
                {
                    if (row.Cells[2].Value == null || row.Cells[2].Value == "0") //qty is null or 0
                    {
                        row.Cells[2].Value = "1"; //set it to assume 1
                        if (row.Cells[4].Value == null)
                        {
                            row.Cells[4].Value = price * 1; //assume the price is price * 1
                            row.Cells[5].Value = originalprice;
                            row.Cells[6].Value = partmargin.ToString("P");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Cells[4].Value = price * Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
                        row.Cells[5].Value = originalprice;
                        row.Cells[6].Value = partmargin.ToString("P");
                    }
                }
                else if (e.ColumnIndex == 2)
                {
                    if (row.Cells[4].Value == null)
                    {
                        row.Cells[4].Value = "0";
                        row.Cells[5].Value = "0";
                        row.Cells[6].Value = "0";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        row.Cells[4].Value = price * Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value);
                        row.Cells[5].Value = originalprice;
                        row.Cells[6].Value = partmargin.ToString("P");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception m)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + m.Message.ToString() + " Source: " + m.Source.ToString() + " " + m.InnerException.ToString(), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            }
        }
```

****This code gets the data table I am working on****

```
public DataTable WorkorderPartItemsTable(int WOID)
{
    ConfigDAL config = new ConfigDAL();
    string connstr = config.GetConnString();
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
    string query;
    Parts part = new Parts();

    query = "SELECT * FROM WorkorderItems WHERE (WorkorderID = @WorkorderID) AND (PartID <> '0')";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
    da.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WorkorderID", WOID);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    conn.Open();
    da.Fill(dt);
    conn.Close();
    return dt;
}
```

p.GetPartItemPrice(ID) and part.LookupPartMargin(ID) are the 2 values that are calculated when ever a change is made to a column in the datagridview. THose do not get calculated when I load the form.

Comment: Yes, code will help - eg which events on the DataGridView are you using?

Comment: You should always post relevant code, because it always helps. This is really at it's core more of a design decision. Do you want to calculate the results each time the form is opened? Or do you want to cache them with the data and update them when more changes are made?

Comment: @RyanGates Both would apply to what I want the design to do.

Comment: I assume you always want to update them with the user's changes. But do you want to save/load previous results and then overwrite them with the calculated results when the form loads?

Comment: I added code - @RyanGates yes, I do want to save/load previous results and only change them if data in the datagrid view changes. I am not storing the results of the calcs. They are on the fly calcs. I think that is why I am not seeing them when I reload the form

Answer (score 0):

on load form event and after binding datatable to datagrid 
then 
change value you want (this change fire cellvalue change events )in the grid by coding 
and then return old value you change
if you don't fire this event twice you can defined bool parameter called it atLoad
and set it = true when load form and then set it false when load finish
use this parameter in datagridWorkorderPartItems_CellValueChanged event 
if (atLoad == true) return;
when change value first once event do nothing
in twice atLoad = false event calculate what you wnat

Answer (score -1):

FormulaEngine is a .NET assembly that enables you to add formula support to your application. It takes care of parsing and evaluating formulas, tracking their dependencies, and recalculating in natural order.

have a look at below article.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17853/Implementing-an-Excel-like-formula-engine

Comment: How is this relevant to the question?